# Scala Curry-Uncurry A Function

Tags: scala, currying

I am trying to create a function that receives a basic curried adder function with 2 parameters and returns uncurried adder function, and vice versa for the currying function(receives uncurried-returns curried) in scala. I am having a hard time figuring the return types of curried functions , can anyone help out?

```
def adderCurried(a: Int)(b: Int): Int = a + b

//define a function that returns uncurried version of this function:

val adderUncurried = toAdderUncurried(adderCurried)

adderUncurried(5,6) // returns 11

def adder(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b

//define a function that returns curried version of this function:

val adderCurried = toAdderCurried(adder)

adderCurried(5,6) // returns 11
```

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is that you are not calling the curried function correctly:

```
adderCurried(5,6) // too many arguments (found 2, expected 1)
```

It should be called in a way that matches the declaration:

```
def adderCurried(a: Int)(b: Int)

adderCurried(5)(6)
```

This gives the clue that there are actually two function invocations here. The first invocation `(5)` returns a function that when called with `(6)` gives the answer. That second function must take an `Int` and return an `Int` so it is `Int => Int`, and this must be what is returned by `adderCurried(5)`.

So `adderCurried` takes an `Int` and returns `Int => Int` so the type is

```
Int => (Int => Int)
```

or just

```
Int => Int => Int
```

You can check this as follows:

```
val check: Int => Int => Int = adderCurried // OK
```

You should be able to create the signatures for `toAdderCurried` and `toAdderUncurried` based on these types.

Answer (score 1):

The `toAdderUncurried` function will be like this.

```scala
def toAdderUncurried(f: Int => Int => Int): (Int, Int) => Int = (x, y) => f(x)(y)
```

You can call it like this.

```
toAdderUncurried(adderCurried)(x, y)
```

And the curry function will be like this.

```scala
def curry(f: (Int, Int) => Int): Int => Int => Int = x => y => f(x, y)
```

you can call it like this

```scala
curry(toAdderUncurried(adderCurried))(x)(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me add [Tim answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70151890/6770614). Right here you have 2 options of your adder function:

- curried `type Curried = (Int => Int => Int)`
- and uncurried `type Uncurried = (Int, Int) => Int`

and your signatures of converting functions should looks like:

```scala
def toAdderUncurried(adderCurried: Curried): Uncurried = ???
def toAdderCurried(adderUncurried: Uncurried): Curried = ???
```